# applying css attributes to child elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I can't understand the behavior of this class:

```
.h-box > div > h2,h3,h4  {
    text-align: center;
}
```

for me it is like this class should applies only to headers nested in  which are nested in .h-box elements.

But in fact it applies also to the h4 header nested directly in .h-box element, why is that? Whats wrong here?

```css
.h-box {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;  
 }
 .h-box > div {
  border: solid gray 2px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0px lightgray;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
 }
 .h-box > div:first-of-type {
            margin-right: 1em;
 } 
 .h-box > * {
  width: 50%;
 }
 .h-box > div > h2,h3,h4  {
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<div class="h-box">
  <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
  </h4>  
</div>

<div class="h-box">                  
  <div>
      <h3> quis nostrud exercitation </h3>
  </div>         
  
  <div>
    <h3> quis nostrud exercitation </h3>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Because that's not the way selectors work. The comma is a delimiter which means that the selector starts again after each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should look like this

```
.h-box > div > h2, .h-box > div > h3, .h-box > div > h4  {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comma separated value is used instead of rewrite the rule several times for a group of selectors. Without the ability to use comma, one would had to do this

```
.h-box > div > h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
.h-box > div > h3 {
    text-align: center;
}
.h-box > div > h4  {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you're not defining a single selector but many. Comma-separated means *multiple selectors must apply these rules*. That is, your CSS code is equivalent to:

```
a, p, span {
   text-align: center;
}
```

In order to apply rules to headings inside the whole `div`, you need:

```
.h-box > div > h2, .h-box > div > h3, .h-box > div > h4  {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Have you ever heard about *CSS transpilers*? [SASS/SCSS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS CSS](http://lesscss.org/) are the most popular ones, and you can implement rules like these in a more readable format:

```
/* Since you can define CSS using hierarchies, it makes more readable */
.h-box > div {
    > {
       h1, h2, h3, h4 {
           text-align: center;
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give it this way:

```
.h-box > div > h2,
.h-box > div > h3,
.h-box > div > h4 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Anything after a `,` is a **new rule**. So you are applying the rule to all the `h3` and `h4` in the document, wherever they are present.

Your code:

```
.h-box > div > h2, h3, h4 {}
```

Is similar to the following:

```
.h-box > div > h2 {}
h3 {}
h4 {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote the following,

```
.h-box > div > h2,h3,h4  {
    text-align: center;
}
```

The browser understands it as,

```
    .h-box > div > h2  {
        text-align: center;
    }
    h3{
        text-align: center;
    }
    h4{
        text-align: center;
}
```

But what you really want is,

```
 .h-box > div > h2,.h-box > div > h3,.h-box > div > h4  {
        text-align: center;
    }
```